# Hibernate persist entity without fetching association object. just by id

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an simple association between 2 entities:

```
public class Car {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    ...

}
```

and

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Car> cars;

    ...

}
```

Then I get some user id from client. For example, userId == 5;
To save car with user I need to do next:

```
User user = ... .findOne(userId);  
Car car = new Car();
car.setUser(user);
... .save(car);
```

> My question is: 
> Can I persist car record without fetching user?

Similarly like I would do by using native SQL query: just insert userId like string(long) in Car table.
 

 With 2nd lvl cache it will be faster but in my opinion I don't need to do extra movements. 
The main reason that I don't want to use native Query is because I have much more difficult associations in my project and I need to .save(car) multiple times. Also i don't want to manually control order of query executions.
**If I use session.createSQLQuery("insert into .....values()") will the Hibernate's batch insert work fine?**

Correct me if I'm wrong.
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Actually the mapping is similar to:

There is @ManyToMany association between User and Car. But cross table is also an entity which is named, for example, Passanger. So the mapping is next:

```
public class User{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = Passenger.class)
    private Set<Passenger> passengers;
}
```

Cross entity

```
@IdClass(value = PassengerPK.class)
public class Passenger {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    private Car car;

    ... other fields ...

}
```

Car entity:

```
public class Car {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "car", targetEntity = Passenger.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Passenger> passengers;
}
```

And the code:

```
List<User> users = ... .findInUserIds(userIds); // find user records where userId is IN userIds - collection with user Ids
Car car = new Car();       //initialization of car's fields is omitted
if (users != null) {
    car.setPassengers(new HashSet<>(users.size()));
    users.forEach((user) -> car.getPassengers().add(new Passenger(user, car)));
}
... .save(car);
```

Comment: Did you show the exact mappings? There are no cascades from `Car` to `User`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic , I've updated the post. And yes, there are cascades.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*"Can I persist car record without fetching user?"*

Yes, that's one of the good sides of Hibernate proxies:

```
User user = entityManager.getReference(User.class, userId); // session.load() for native Session API  
Car car = new Car();
car.setUser(user);
```

The key point here is to use [EntityManager.getReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-):

> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched.

Hibernate will just create the proxy based on the provided id, without fetching the entity from the database.

*"If I use session.createSQLQuery("insert into .....values()") will the Hibernate's batch insert work fine?"*

No, it will not. Queries are executed immediately.

Comment: You are right. But I have another question if you allow. I cannot call .merge(car) because of exception: detached entity passed to persist? It's not an option to call saveOrUpdate() because I need removeOrphan.

Comment: I suggest you open a different question for that, because it seems to be a different issue. Post the entire stack trace of the exception there, so that we know which entity is detached, etc.

Comment: I've opened new question. Please, visit [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038319/hibernate-merge-cascade-orphanremoval-on-persistent-detached-entity)

Comment: with eclipselink you don't have to fetch the reference at all. It's handled on the way. Is it possible to configure hibernate the same way?

Comment: This seems ok for a single object. Is there any option for saving list of entity. For example If i want to save List of Car with different user?

Comment: This is really a pity in terms of API design IMO.

Comment: What if you don't have the id of the associated entity?

Answer (score 5):

If someone is using Spring Data JPA: The same can be achieved in Spring Data JPA can be done using the method

[`JpaRepository.getReferenceById(ID id)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getReferenceById-ID-)

This replaced the former
[`getOne(ID)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.7.0/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-)

Comment: updated the answer to take recent API changes into account.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate users can implement this method:

```
public <T extends Object> T getReferenceObject(Class<T> clazz, Serializable id) {
        return getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    }
```

And call like:

```
MyEntity myEntity = getRefererenceObject(MyEntity.class, 1);
```

You can change id type to Integer or Long as per your entity model.
Or T can be inherited from your BaseEntity if you have one base class for all entities.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach works for me:

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(userId);
car.setUser(user);
```

Comment: This is a transient entity, it's not persisted.