# How to add property class by it's id with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Have stucked a bit and think - need help.
Suppose I have a class Message, which is a child for a Forum. They have One-to-Many relation in annotation. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message", catalog="catalog")
public class Message implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="IDMessage", unique = true)
    private int idMessage;

    @Column(name="Title", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="Message", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="IDForum")
    private Forum forum;
}
```

Problem:

I don't want to retrieve the Forum object by it's id, attach it to the message and only then save the message.
So I have started to create a wrapper, which will be like:

```
public class MessageDto {

    private int idMessage;
    private String title;
    private String message;
    private int idForum;
}
```

And use it whenever I am saving/updating. But I have a very strong feeling that I am doing it wrong.

Simple guiding, in which direction to look for the answer, will be a great help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32037084/4754790

Comment: Good suggestion and one more solution. In my case I have used proposition of German since it appeared first. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hibernate, you don't need to fetch the object if it already exists. Just create a new Forum with the id (you should have it already).
Example:

```
Message message = new Message();
...
...
Forum forum = new Forum();
forum.setId(yourId);
message.setForum(forum);

messageRepository.save(message);
```

Hibernate should save it OK.

Comment: Yep, all good. Must say - I am very impressed with this functionality. Thank you a lot!