# How can I save an object with a foreign key if I just know the foreign key id and not the complete entity?

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate

I am working on converting an existing project over to use Hibernate. I am using Mysql for the database. I have a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   private Long userId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "group_id_user")
   private Group group;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

and a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "group_id")
   private Long groupId;

   @Column(name="group_name")
   private String groupName;

   ...
   // getters and setters....   
}
```

I am running into issues while trying to add a User to the DB. The client is sending over data in JSON format, for example:

```
{
   "user":
   {
      "name": "John",
      "groupId": 3
   }
}
```

This format matches the `user` table which has a `user_id`, `group_id`, and `username` column. I used to be able to convert the JSON object directly to a `User` object using the code below:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
User user = gson.fromJson(userJSON.toString(), User.class);
```

but now that I am using Hibernate my `User` class does not have a member variable called `groupId`. Instead it has a member variable of type `Group` called `group`. The above code creates a `User` object with no `group` member and when I save it to the database the column `group_id` is set to null.

**Is there a good/easy way to create a `User` object that can be saved to the DB from the JSON object with just the `groupId` instead of an actual `Group` object?**

I don't think it would be a good idea to have to change the JSON object that the client is sending to the server. Also I would hope I wouldn't have to parse the JSON object to get the `groupId` and then perform a query to get the `Group` object from the database, and then use that `Group` object and the JSON object to create a `User` object to be saved.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929447/hibernate-persist-entity-without-fetching-association-object-just-by-id if you're using the JPA API (EntityManager.getReference())

Comment: @JBNizet I think the question is more about how to deserialize the json message in correct way that handles the case where the `User` object has a reference to a `Group` object, instead of `Long groupId, it is not about `Hibernate`

Comment: In this case, the answer is to get the goupId from the received JSON, use em.getReference() to get the group, ans store it into the user. JSON received from the browser should not be derserialized into an entity. That's not what it represents. It represents input from the browser. Just decouple inputs/commands from entities, and everything becomes simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @JBNizet I am currently not using the EntityManager class. I am using org.hibernate.Session. It looks like if I get the groupId from the JSON and then use `Group group = (Group) session.load(Group.class, groupId); user.setGroup(group);` it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, that's why I marked this question as a duplicate of a question where the answer tells to do just that.